# Unity game: database VS large number of text files

Tags: database, sqlite, unity-game-engine, mobile, nosql

I maintain a puzzle game developed in Unity3D (iOS / Android).

Puzzles are defined in plain text files, and grouped into packs. Below is a sample JSON file (that the app downloads from the remote server) with the definition of a pack and the puzzles in it (usually 10-50 puzzles per pack):

```
{
  "id": "pack.2000",
  "title": "Pack 2000",
  "puzzles": [
    {
      "id": "pack.2000.0001",
      "number": 1,
      "title": "Puzzle 1",
      "contents": "... puzzle contents in plain txt .."
    },
    {
      "id": "pack.2000.0002",
      "number": 2,
      "title": "Puzzle 2",
      "contents": "... puzzle contents in plain txt .."
    },
    {
      "id": "pack.2000.0003",
      "number": 2,
      "title": "Puzzle 3",
      "contents": "... puzzle contents in plain txt .."
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

To track available puzzle packs, the app maintains a local JSON file with an index and compares it with the remote index:

```
{
  "packs": [
    {
      "id": "pack.2000"
    },
    {
      "id": "pack.1999"
    },
    {
      "id": "pack.1998"
    }
    ...
  ]
}
```

After the index diff is performed and any packs downloaded, the JSON file is parsed and each puzzle is saved into a separated text file in the client app, e.g.:

- `pack.2000.0001.txt`
- `pack.2000.0002.txt`
- `pack.2000.0003.txt`, ...

This approach has the advantage that I can easily load a puzzle with it's id by just reading a text file specifying the .txt path, without having to parse and read more complex structures (an entire JSON document, opening a database, etc.)

The problem is that my app currently has reached 2000 packs with ~15 puzzles in each `= 2000*15 = 30000` .txt files (~1KB each) stored in the app's folder, and I'm afraid this approach isn't scalable for the future.

Note that the data defined above is only for the raw puzzle data, the app still creates separated .txt files to save user state, like the user's progress in *each puzzle*, e.g.: `userid_progress_pack.2000.0001.txt`

I've received feedback from a few users complaining that they ran some sort of 'file cleaner' apps and found that the app contains thousands of *very small* text files (and thus, subject to an accidental 'clean up'). Also, I'm aware that there are some features that I could take advantage like Android's [android:allowBackup](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup.html), and that the large number of files wouldn't be the best solution.

Is it a problem to have so many files in a single folder, like filesystem limitations or issues on mobile devices? Should I consider migrating to another storage solution (binary sqlite database, nosqlite JSON database)?

Comment: well you can store that file content in a field in a database on a website and go get it on request..

Comment: You could split them up into reasonable junks and only load the one you need .. additionally caching some until a certain threshold is reached .. look into [Addressables](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/com.unity.addressables.html) for instance

Comment: You also might want to consider using a more dense serialization .. for instance JSON bit without indentation, spaces and line breaks - or a simple CSV format .. for instance it could simply be `pack.2000, pack.2001,pack.2002,...` or even binary right away .. and like do you really really need that `pack.` prefix ...?

Answer (score 0):

One Solution is to store nothing in device,
Store list of available pack and pack details in database.
and query depending on game structure.
one option is firebase real-time
its structure is JSON (nested JSON);